# Main is usually a function?

Tags: c, function, compiler-errors, syntax-error, program-entry-point

I do this question because i was doing a basic program, and i have a warning when i compilate it, it says "warning: 'main' is usually a function"" and then make a error of syntaxis in the same line.
My program is about a palindrome, in spanish we say "capicua".
Thanks for the help.
I program in C.

```
int T=10;

int CargarVector(char Vec[T]);
int escapicua(char Vec[T])
int main()
{                            //here is the error!!
    char Vec[T];
    cargarVector(Vec);
    escapicua(Vec);
    return 0;
}
int CargarVector(int Vec[T])
{
    int i=0;
    printf("ingrese letra");
    aux=getche();
    while(aux!='.'&&i<T)
    {
        while(aux<'a'||aux>'Z')
        {
            printf("Error, ingrese letra del Abcdario")
            aux=getche();
        }
        Vec[i]=aux;
        i++;
        printf("ingrese letra");
        aux=getche();
    }
    r=i;
    return 0;
}
int escapicua(char Vec[T])
{
    int i,c;
    for(i=0;i<(T/2),i++)
    {
        if(Vec[i]!=Vec[(T-1)]
           {
               C++
           }
           if(C>0)
            {
                printf("No es capicua");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Es capicua")
            }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Firstly, it should be either `int main( void )` or `int main( ... )` where the `...` are two arguments from the OS.

Comment: I strongly advise you to start coding in english as soon as possible. It helps when googling for help or asking questions. And once you start coding in teams there is no way around it anyway.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to translate the words to spanish, i don't go to do it again, and you got reason about this.

Comment: @JacobPollack: You mean `int main(void)` or `int main(into argc, char *argv[])`. `...` is actually a valid token in a function prototype, just not in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you forgot to put a semicolon after the forward declaration on the previous line:

```
int escapicua(char Vec[T]);
//           Here ------- ^
```

Note that array size and parameter names are ignored in function declarations, so the declaration below would be equivalent:

```
int escapicua(char[]);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int escapicua(char Vec[T]);
                       // ^
```

You forgot the `;` after function forward declaration.